# Not able to call node service from angular

Tags: node.js, angular

I was learning to call node from angular,in my component i had the following code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {GetvalidationService} from '../_services/getvalidation.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service:GetvalidationService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getStudentData();
  }
  studentDetails :any =[]  
  getStudentData(){
        this.service.getStudentData().subscribe()
  }

}
```

the service is defined as followed

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetvalidationService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  authenticateLogin(userDetails){
   
    return this.http.post("/api/login",userDetails)
  }

  getStudentData(){
    return this.http.get("/api/student");
  }
}
```

and I have done the proxy.conf.json setting in package.json as well

my proxy.conf.json looks like

```
{
    "/api/*":{
        "target":"http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathrewrite":{"^/api":""}
    }
}
```

inspite of this when i make a call for student the angular service makes call to http://localhost:4200/api/student instead of the node service on port 3000 where would i be going wrong ? I use npm run start to start the angular app

Comment: What makes you think it's being redirected?

Comment: You *should* see it calling :4200 on the browser, the proxy happens once the Webpack dev server receives the request. See e.g. https://github.com/textbook/starter-kit/wiki/Architecture#development-mode (not Angular, but using the same proxy). What makes you think it's *not working*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe because on the node end i have console.log and its not writing anything

Comment: getStudentData(){
        this.service.getStudentData().subscribe((data)=>data)
  }

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what's on the backend? Can you successfully make requests from another client (e.g. curl)? Your path rewrite seems suspicious.

Answer (score -1):

You have to define your baseUrl, if you do not do that then you end up with one you defined in your angular port options, i.e. localhost:4200.

So the piece of code required to connect to the node is this:

I suggest keeping the api url in environment, so that you can easily move it around different environments like this:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  api: 'http://localhost:3000'
};
```

Your Service ts file will then include the `api` from enviornment:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetvalidationService {


private baseUrl= environment.api + '/api';  // URL to your web api


  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  authenticateLogin(userDetails){
   
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/login`,userDetails)
  }

  getStudentData(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/student`);
  }
}
```